# Do I have an Ethernet adapter?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, internet, connection

I'm not too familiar with the technology/terms here. I'm trying to troubleshoot why I have a wireless connection but not a wired one to the internet. The connection is coming in fine, and I have several devices on wifi, but my desktop connect with Powerline does not have an internet connection. Here are the network adapters in my device manager:

[image]

Comment: As per the below answers - you have Ethernet Adapter on the PC and it seems to be working (as it is not disabled, or showing any exclamation point). If you are not getting any IP address from your PowerLine, maybe your powerline is not connected properly? Can you test using a different machine? Check your Network Adapter settings?

Comment: @Darius I've selected an answer for this question, but I'll create a separate one later for that specific issue.

Comment: @Darius If you're still feeling helpful... https://superuser.com/questions/1282276/no-internet-connection-through-lan

Comment: That question is no longer there? (can't see it)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Realktek PCIe **GBE** Family Controller"

where GBE means Gigabit Ethernet. So thats a wired NIC.

You'd be better off checking in control panel for "Network Connections" though.

Answer (score 2):

The "Realtek PCIe GBE Family Controller" is a dead giveaway that you have an Ethernet (the E in GBE) adapter somewhere.